# cordova 1.7 iOS audiorecord plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, avaudiorecorder

I've implemented the audio record plugin on IOS using phonegap/cordova 1.7. IOS5.1

I'm using it over the standard media.startrecord() function as I want to change the bitrate to reduce the size of the file.

It works fine in the simulator.

On the real iphone it records successfully once but subsequently refuses.. it seems to work but on playback I'm getting an error 4 MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED

I've created a new project with just a bare bones record and playback and I'm still getting the same issue.

Here's the test code - It's very basic - just a couple of links to record two separate files and play them back.  The setTimeout is there to record just a couple of seconds of audio each time.

I've googled til I've worn out my fingerprints but haven't found a resolution.

Any insight you can give would be very gratefully received.

I'm wondering if I'm failing to close out the recording/playback properly? Or are files referenced differently on the sim v the iPhone?

Many thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />       

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var fs,mediaRec=null, recInterval,recordSettings = {"FormatID": "kAudioFormatULaw","SampleRate": 16000.0,"NumberOfChannels": 1,"LinearPCMBitDepth": 16};

    function recfile1() {recordAudio("test.wav");}
    function recfile2() {recordAudio("test2.wav");}
    function success(){console.log("ok");}
    function recordAudio(fname) {
        fs.root.getFile(fname, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(entry){            
            mediaRec = new Media(entry.fullPath, success, function(){alert("failed");});
            mediaRec.startRecordWithSettings(recordSettings);
            recInterval = setTimeout(function() {
                mediaRec.stopRecordWithSettings();
            }, 2000);
        }, function(){console.log("error");});
    }

    function playfile(fname) {
        var my_media;
        fs.root.getFile(fname, {create: false, exclusive: false}, 
            function success(entry) {
                my_media = new Media(entry.fullPath,function(){console.log("ok");},function(err){alert(err.code+" "+err.message);});
                my_media.play();
            }, 
            function() {
                console.log("not found file");
            }
        );
    }

    function onBodyLoad() {     
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){fs=fileSystem;}, function(){console.log("failed");});
    Media.prototype.startRecordWithSettings = function(options) {
        Cordova.exec(null, null, "AudioRecord","startAudioRecord", [this.id, this.src, options]);
    };
    Media.prototype.stopRecordWithSettings = function() {
        Cordova.exec(null, null, "AudioRecord","stopAudioRecord", [this.id, this.src]);
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<a onclick="playfile('test.wav');">play</a>
    <a style='margin-top:100px;' onclick="recfile1();">record 1</a>
    <a style='margin-top:100px;' onclick="recfile2();">record 2</a>
    <a onclick="playfile('test2.wav');">play2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Further testing shows that I can record any number of files successfully.  This code then will play back any file but as soon as you play one back, you can't play back any others and the error 4 MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED appears

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue on WP7 and Android with Cordova 2.0.0...

Comment: Unfortunately not and at the moment I've reverted to native CD quality recording on the iPhone. Still working on this and I'll post progress